# How do I fix a ffi_c (LoadError) given by line 127 of kernel_require.rb (I'm using Ruby 2.3 on Windows 10)

Tags: ruby, mingw32

Whenever I try to run my Ruby program I get this error:

C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi_c (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in`rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:6:in`rescue in '
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in`require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/windows/root_certs.rb:2:in`'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/windows.rb:7:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/windows.rb:7:in`'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in`require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in`require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/rest_client.rb:2:in`'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in`rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from form_response_transfer.rb:3:in [main method]

The program (form_response_transfer.rb) used to work fine, but now, there seems to be some problem with my rest-client gem. I haven't changed any of the code in the program since it last worked, so I'm not sure exactly what I did to cause this error. In general, gems that end with X64-mingw32 have been giving me problems lately (some other examples include nokogiri, sqlite3, and pg). How should I go about trying to fix this error? Could there be some problem with how Ruby is set up on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall FFI gem

```
gem uninstall ffi
```

and then reinstall it with below command:

```
gem install ffi --platform=ruby
```

It worked on my side (Win7 x64)